# Programmatic button click throws 'System.StackOverflowException' exception

Tags: c#, button, click, stack-overflow, simulate

I have written a WinForms program in C#.Net to click a button programmatically within a password form.

`Form1` loads and shows `Form2` as a dialogue box.

The application will close if DialogResult is anything other that DialogResult.OK.

So far I have a button click event, which is coded as follows:

```
 if (txtpass.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to enter a password", "Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                txtpass.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                if (txtpass.Text == "1234")
                {
                    radButton1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    radButton1.PerformClick();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password Incorrect", "Password", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    txtpass.Text = "";
                    txtpass.Focus();
                }
            }
```

I use `radButton1.PerformClick();`, but running the program gives me the following message:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

I'm unsure what is causing this exception to throw.

Comment: Forgot to add, this code is inside the button that it is trying to simulate

Comment: Can you post some more about what you are trying to do? Essentially it looks like you're tacking the problem in the wrong way, hence your problem. Might be able to suggest a better way if we know what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit** Not a guess.  Telling the button to click itself from within itself is most definitely causing an infinite loop.  This causes the method to get called over and over, filling up the stack and causing it to overflow.

My guess is that calling `PerformClick()` is causing the current method you posted to get called again, thus causing an infinite call loop and resulting in a `StackOverflowException`.

To prevent this, you need to fix the logic somewhere in your code so that:

```
if (txtpass.Text == "1234")
```

evaluates to `false` and the click method doesn't get called over and over.  You can probably achieve this by setting `txtpass.Text = ""` right before you cause it to click itself again.

Comment: Ah I see, any ideas on how to get around this?

Comment: "You can probably achieve this by setting txtpass.Text = "" right before you cause it to click itself again."  But then that will throw the "invalid password" message box - so what's the point?

Comment: @Andy I see that, the logic in the button needs to be reworked a lot it seems.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would manually call the event that you are trying to run.

E.g. if you have a method

```
button1_Click(object sender, ButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Then you would call the following in your code:

```
button1_Click(this, new ButtonEventArgs());
```

I think maybe you need to explain some logic in your code though, as it's not clear what you're trying to do. The StackOverflow probably because you're doing

PerformClick() -> PerformClick() -> PerformClick() because your "1234" text never changes between calls.

Comment: This would also cause an infinite loop if it's called from within Button1_Click.

Comment: Andy, yeah I know, was just the first part of my answer... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To call the event handler again from inside you could use the following code:

```
if (txtpass.Text)
{
    case "1234":
        radButton1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

        txtpass.Text = "12345";

        radButton1.PerformClick();

        break;

    default:
        case "12345":
        break;

}
```

Comment: This is because I need to set the dialogue button up, but I dont want to do this without them entering the password, but this means that they have to click it twice

Answer (score 1):

Is the `PerformClick()` inside the button's click event? If so, that's where you're going wrong because you're throwing your application into an infinite loop.

User clicks button,
.NET runs Click() handler,
Button clicks `PerformClick()`,
.NET runs Click() handler,
Button clicks `PerformClick()`,
.NET runs Click() handler,
Button clicks `PerformClick()`,

etc.

Is `form1` definitely calling `ShowDialog()` on `form2`, and not just `Show()`?

Instead of `radButton1.DialogResult`, try setting `this.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK`.

The `DialogResult` property on a button tells .NET which `DialogResult` to assign to the `Form` when the `Button` is clicked.

Comment: Thanks, but I have sorted the problem

Answer (score 0):

A stack overflow happens usually because method is indefinitely calling itself, because each time a method is called, an entry is added to the stack to the point where there is no more stack left.

To stop the recursion, remove the line `radButton1.PerformClick();`